# <iframe> no se autoreproduce en pantalla modo responsive

Tags: html, youtube, iframe

Tengo el siguiente `iframe` con autoplay, en mi Google Chrome modo normal se reproduce perfecto, pero si habilito las herramientas de desarrollo y pongo la pantalla en modo responsive, deja de autoreproducirse, quedando únicamente la vista previa del vídeo con el botón de reproducir en medio.

No he podido comprobar si esto sucede realmente en navegadores móviles ¿alguien sabe si realmente no funciona y, si es así, ¿qué debo hacer para que se autoreproduzca?

Mi iframe:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0dbig-gLoCo?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=0dbig-gLoCo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En dispositivos móviles (Android e iOS) esta característica no funciona, al parecer para evitar descargas no solicitadas a través de redes de telefonía celular por cuenta del usuario. Dicha advertencia aparece en esta página: [Youtube player API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

> ## Reproducción automática y reproducción generada por secuencias de comandos
>
> En algunos navegadores móviles (como Chrome y Safari), el elemento `<video>` de HTML5 solo permite la reproducción si esta se inicia mediante una interacción del usuario (por ejemplo, al tocar en el reproductor).
>
> Debido a esta restricción, las funciones y los parámetros como `autoplay` , `playVideo()` , `loadVideoById()` no funcionan en todos los entornos móviles.

Comment: Bien visto :D te he editado la respuesta. Si no te parece bien, revierte ^^'  Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Así queda más claro, ¡gracias por la edición!

Comment: Mas que nada era para que no tuvieran que salir de SOes y buscar la seccion que lo explica ^^